# Closed (Off Topic) Questions show up in "Related Questions" list - feature request.

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to prevent questions that were closed as "Off Topic" from showing up in the related questions list on the right hand sidebar?

Sample question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/905/free-av-firewall-for-windows-suggestion-closed

When the question shows up in the list it just has the original subject and doesn't indicate that it's been closed until you click on it.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good that closed questions show up:

- If it was closed as duplicate, the original question will be linked. It may be phrased in a different way so it might not show up.
- If it was closed as off topic or migrated, it's good to tell the new asker that the question is not wanted here.

That leaves the cases of poor posting that don't make any sense at all. But we only have very little of them, and the number of (down) votes is visible.

Comment: Then maybe an option to hide like there is for tags to ignore?