# (Closed) questions in top questins active and hot

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I found [Closed] questions when I was was randomly browsing the [active](https://security.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) and [hot](https://security.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot) questions tabs. And I must say that I can't say that I feel that closed questions should be active. And I feel that a hot question is anything but closed.

I have seen [Closed (Off Topic) Questions show up in “Related Questions” list - feature request.](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/closed-off-topic-questions-show-up-in-related-questions-list-feature-reques) but I feel that this is a different issue.

Or have I misunderstood how [active](https://security.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) and [hot](https://security.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'active' tab is a list of the questions sorted by when they were asked, answered, or updated. The 'hot' tab is sorted by the [hotness algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions).

A closed question is not deleted. It can be edited, fixed, and re-opened. We need people to see closed questions so appropriate actions can be taken (fixed or deleted). A question being closed does not affect where you would expect them to appear in the "active" or "hot" sort order.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explaining how the system works.